# JScrollPane problem

Tags: java, swing, layout, jscrollpane

I have made a program with a scroll pane, but it is not working. Please look at the source code:

JInfoView.java

```
package view;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class JInfoView extends JPanel {
    private JButton button = new JButton("ADD");
    private JButton buttonDelete = new JButton("DEL");
    private JTextField input = new JTextField("Text", 5);
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Test");
    public JInfoView() {
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.add(button);
        this.add(buttonDelete);
        this.add(input);
        this.add(label);
    }
}
```

JMainView.java

```
package view;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import view.JInfoView;

public class JMainView extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mypanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 30, 50));
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mypanel);
    public JMainView() {
        super("Simple Example");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        container.add(scrollPane);

        scrollPane.setVisible(true);
        scrollPane.setAutoscrolls(true); 

        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());       
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView()); 
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JMainView app = new JMainView();
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I've read a tutorial which says:

```
//In a container that uses a BorderLayout:
textArea = new JTextArea(5, 30);
...
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
...
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 110));
...
add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I've done the same steps,

```
private JPanel mypanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 30, 50));
private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mypanel);
```

And then added scrollpane:

```
container.add(scrollPane);
```

Where is a mistake?
EDIT:
The problem is that the scroll pane is not working. I add many JInfoView to the mypanel,
but scroll is not working..

Comment: you haven't described what is not working.

Comment: Don't make us to copy your code and test it and see the bug. Describe the problem as said by @Mat: what is not working?

Comment: Sorry, i've just edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to add `scrollPane.setPreferredSize` call like this:

```
public class JMainView extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mypanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 30, 50));
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mypanel);
    public JMainView() {
        super("Simple Example");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        container.add(scrollPane);

        scrollPane.setVisible(true);
        scrollPane.setAutoscrolls(true);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400)); //========== this was missed

        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        this.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JMainView app = new JMainView();
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ maximus and definitions for new 'JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 30, 50));' doesn9t corresponent with number of added 'mypanel.add(new JInfoView());'

Comment: @ mKorbel why not? new GridLayout(0, 1, 30, 50) means that there can be any number of rows, and only one column. Isn't it so and did you mean that?

Comment: @ denisk does your answer means, that the preffered size of scrollpane changes while adding new elements to mypanel?

Comment: @maximus: I'm not aware if it changes or not (I guess not), it just has to be specified

Comment: Calling `setPreferredSize(Dimension)` is neither **desirable** (the *vast majority* of the time) nor **necessary** in this case.

Answer (score 5):

It seems to work OK if the `JScrollPane` is in the `CENTER` of a `BorderLayout`.  E.G.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class JMainView extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mypanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 30, 50));
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mypanel);
    public JMainView() {
        super("Simple Example");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Container container = this.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        container.add(scrollPane);

        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
        mypanel.add(new JInfoView());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JMainView app = new JMainView();
        // important!
        app.pack();
        // show the scroll bars by compressing the GUI height
        app.setSize(
            (int)app.getSize().getWidth()+30, 
            (int)app.getSize().getHeight()/2);
        app.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class JInfoView extends JPanel {
    private JButton button = new JButton("ADD");
    private JButton buttonDelete = new JButton("DEL");
    private JTextField input = new JTextField("Text", 5);
    private JLabel label = new JLabel("Test");
    public JInfoView() {
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.add(button);
        this.add(buttonDelete);
        this.add(input);
        this.add(label);
    }
}
```